# Best Practice for Shopping-Cart like functionality in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, session, sharepoint-2010, concurrency

I need to build a Price Quote system on SharePoint, where people can go in to an existing website and instead of adding items to a cart (this company doesn't sell direct) they can add items to a quote, and then print the quote and take it to a dealer.

The issue is, SharePoint doesn't do Session well, and we don't want to mess with the server in any way we don't have to.

How should I best keep a concurrent list of products and accessories in a cart-like way, without using session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily enable Session state on a SharePoint web app via the web.config file(s).  However, from a scale perspective it might be better to employ a [cookie-based](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) approach instead.